# How to use result of one query in another query

Tags: mysql

I have one query like

```
SELECT lft,rgt
FROM  `navigation` 
WHERE  `slug` =  'case-studies';
```

output of this query
lft rgt
28  89

Now i want to use this result in another query in same table

```
SELECT * FROM `navigation` WHERE `lft` between 28 and 89
```

But i want to do this dynamically So that i don't need to pass "left", "right"
value again and again
Now i want to know, how can i do something like below.

```
SELECT * FROM `navigation` WHERE `lft` between :lft and :rgt
```

Comment: See JOINs, and generally best not to use '-' in a table/column identifier

Comment: Show the table structure. Hint: join is what you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a self-join:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM `navigation` t1
INNER JOIN `navigation` t2
ON t1.`lft` between t2.`lft` and t2.`rgt`
WHERE t2.`slug` =  'case-studies';
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT n.* 
FROM `navigation` AS n
CROSS JOIN (
   SELECT lft, rgt
   FROM  `navigation` 
   WHERE  `slug` =  'case-studies') AS t
WHERE n.`lft` between t.lft and t.rgt
```

You can use this `CROSS JOIN` to get `lft`, `rgt` values as long as the subquery returns exactly one record.

Comment: #1052 - Column 'lft' in where clause is ambiguous

Comment: @daulat Sorry, there was an error in my query. Please check the edit I made.